# How to run only the LINUX kernel and User programs

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

is it possible to run only Linux kernel on a system which will load user program instead of an operating system?

I want to work with a raspberry pi with Linux kernel. I am trying to create a server and client programs on raspberry pi and for this i need only a kernel which will work on network drivers.

I want raspberry pi to run the programs when i switch ON it.

Thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: I'm working on something similar, but without the Linux kernel: http://ellcc.org/blog/?p=22979

Comment: Richard Pennigton, thanks for reply.. In my project i want to use socket programs in order to develop basic server and client.. In ellcc.org i saw bare metal programming.. So without kernel, do i need to develop network components?

Comment: I'm finishing up the threading and virtual memory parts and will be adding networking (with lwip) next.

Comment: [I answered this question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175386/run-only-the-linux-kernel-and-user-programs/175408#175408) (which is where this question belongs, but U&L closed the question as unclear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. configuration depends of which init system you choose to use. 
In a few words, in the boot process, once the linux kernel is up, it launches the first process named init.
And the init start other processes as needed.
That's what you should use to start your program automatically.

Well, you'll also need to make your own system with tools like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) for example.

Comment: thanks for your response sir :)
would you like to share any relevant work info or links then it will be very helpful for me.. :D

Comment: I can go through configuration and compilation procedure. Is init is available as code format? .. And i will go through buildroot as you mentioned.. Thankyou